# Ordering existing LOTR guides

Tags: discussion

I would like to reach a consensus on the existing LOTR guide questions (reducing the count for unanswered questions in the process).

What do you think about closing them (or deleting them) in favor of having a single CW question for all guides about LOTR?

That question exists now, but it's currently closed: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17/lord-of-the-rings-online-guide

Should we open it, and close the rest (or just delete them) as duplicates of that one?

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63/lord-of-the-rings-online-weaponsmithing-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101/lord-of-the-rings-online-tailoring-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113/lord-of-the-rings-online-scholar-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110/lord-of-the-rings-online-forestor-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106/lord-of-the-rings-online-farmer-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89/lord-of-the-rings-online-prospector-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136/lord-of-the-rings-online-burglar-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135/lord-of-the-rings-online-rune-keeper-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133/lord-of-the-rings-online-lore-master-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128/lord-of-the-rings-online-ranger-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123/lord-of-the-rings-online-jeweller-guide
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119/lord-of-the-rings-online-woodworker-guide

Comment: "or just delete them" - I thought no one has the ability to delete yet :)

Comment: @oak, not yet, but we could ask a moderator to do it if we all agree... anyway, we'll have 10K users soon enough (the suggestion was thinking ahead)

Comment: @Oak the owner can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good to me.

I don't see any value in these distinct questions right now, while the "where can I find good guides for game X" feels like a relatively solid question.

Comment: Agreed. I really don't think "Where can I find good guides for element Y of game X" is something that should not be able to be answered in a general question of "Where can I find good guides for game X". By definition, the latter should have the answer for the former.

Comment: Rather than good guides, the question should ask about information. In which case I still feel we do need separate questions, but not filled with links to the same sources

Comment: I changed 'guide' to 'information' in the question, as anyone else could have.